# Undefined method delete_if for NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, validation, null

I'm trying to validate redemption codes

```
@redemption_codes = Account.where(:redeemed == false).map(&:redemption_code)

validates :code, inclusion: { in: @redemption_codes }
before_create :remove_code

def remove_code
  @redeemed = Account.where(:redeemed == true).map(&:redemption_code)
  @redemption_codes.delete_if{|code|@redeemed.include?(code)}
end
```

If a code has already been redeemed, I want to remove it from the array, so it's no longer included.

Here I get

```
Undefined method delete_if for nil:NilClass
```

The value of @redemption_codes is `nil`

If I type in a value that is not included in the array, I get an error flash message.

When I type in a value included in the array, it works. In other words, it works if I comment out the `remove_code` method.

Problem is `@redemption_codes` is set in stone. If a value is updated from `:redeemed = false` to `:redeemed = true`, it won't disappear from the array.

That's why I tried to create a custom validation message, but it didn't work.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: The code `Account.where(:redeemed == false)` doesn't make sense. The syntax is `Account.where(redeemed: false)`.

Comment: Or, `Account.where(:redeemed => false)`. Looks like this may be a syntactical misread or typo on the part of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

That is the incorrect syntax.

```
Account.where(:redeemed == false)
```

should be

```
Account.where(redeemed: false)
```

You should try something like this

```
def validate_code
  @redemption_codes = Account.where(redeemed: false).map(&:redemption_code)
  errors[:base] << "Invalid Redemption Code" unless @redemption_codes.include?(self.code)
end
```

You could also use the `uniqueness` validator

```
validates :code, inclusion: { in: @redemption_codes }, uniqueness: true
```

This ensures that a redeemed account will not be valid